# Which vim mechanism should I use to implement Markdown list indentation?

Tags: vim, markdown

I'm looking to beef up the Markdown capabilities of vim a bit (https://github.com/plasticboy/vim-markdown), namely to add some support for auto-creating the next list item while indenting everything properly.

My question is, what vim mechanism is best to implement this in? Is this a task for the highlighting file? Should I cobble together something in SnipMate? I'm glad to do any homework necessary, but I'd like to know where's the best place to start.

Comment: Any luck with this?  I am considering delving into this issue myself.

Comment: None I'm afraid. Ran into some other high-priority issues so I didn't really get started. Good luck with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on a quick snoop through the help, `formatoptions` and `formatlistpat` and the related `fo-table` look like good places to start.  I'd start by reading those and then finding existing plugins that use them and figure out how they work.